# Pretty-printable std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, inheritance, aggregation

I would like to be able to print a regex.  For legitimate reasons, `std::regex` does not keep a copy of the textual regular expression, so we have to wrap it ourselves.  Yet, simple aggregation is quite verbose.  Is there a recommended practice?  Would public inheritance, as below, feature nasty issues?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

template <
  class CharT,
  class Traits = std::regex_traits<CharT>
  >
class basic_pp_regex
  : public std::basic_regex<CharT, Traits>
{
public:
  using self = basic_pp_regex;
  using super = std::basic_regex<CharT, Traits>;

  template <typename... Args>
  basic_pp_regex(std::string pretty, Args&&... args)
    : super{pretty, std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    , _pretty{std::move(pretty)}
  {}

  basic_pp_regex(basic_pp_regex const&) = default;
  basic_pp_regex(basic_pp_regex&&) = default;
  // The default regex matches nothing.
  basic_pp_regex()
    : basic_pp_regex{"$."}
  {}

  friend
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, self const& s)
  {
    return o << std::quoted(s._pretty, '/');
  }

private:
  std::string _pretty;
};

using pp_regex = basic_pp_regex<char>;

int main()
{
  auto re = pp_regex("/foo");
  auto s = "/root/foo/bar";
  std::cout << s << " ~ " << re << " =  " << std::regex_search(s, re) << '\n';
}
```

which gives:

```
/root/foo/bar ~ /\/foo/ =  1
```

Comment: Having never done this myself, a couple dangers come to mind: 1) No virtual functions in `std::regex`, so no polymorphism.  I think this is not a problem in your case because you are only adding functions and not overriding anything.  And a `basic_pp_regex` should continue working as expected from a context that expects a regular `std::regex`.  2.) Slicing.  Again I think it is fine in this case because your `_pretty` member doesn't mean anything except in the `operator<<` that you added.  I would definitely leave good comments because you don't want future devs to break these two assumptions.

Comment: Beware `basic_regex::assign()` and `swap()`. These will modify the contents of `basic_regex` portion of your class, while keeping `_pretty` intact with stale data.